# Some URL are not opening in external Browser while invoking from app

Tags: android, android-webview, android-browser

When I am trying to open a URL by invoking a native browser from my app ,it does not load from the app. It does not launches the browser also.

Nor I am not getting any exception. I used `try/Catch`. Similarly I used 
webView client also, but not getting any of exceptions.

```
                   WebView webview = new WebView(this);
                   webview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                   webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
                   webview.setInitialScale(0);
                   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);

                   System.out.println("Within in WebView>>>> Before Load URL>>"+url);
                   webview.loadUrl(url);
                   webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

Did anyone faced similar sort of issue?

Answer (score 0):

This line prevents your links from loading the external browser:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

If you want to load your links in the browser delete it. Well if I have understood your question.